# wifi not working after upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 <access denied>

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

Hardline working fine; just no WiFi.

`$ lspci -v | grep -iA7 network`

```
0b:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1395 WLAN Mini-Card
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
Memory at fe7fc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
```

`$ lsmod | grep b43-pci-bridge`

`$ lsmod | grep b43`

```
b43                   387371  0 
bcma                   52096  1 b43
mac80211              626489  1 b43
cfg80211              484040  2 b43,mac80211
ssb                    62379  1 b43
```

`$ nm-tool`

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            sky2
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        00:21:9B:ED:A6:84

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.8
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do:

```
sudo apt-get purge b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

reboot

Comment: Another option is the package `bcmwl-kernel-source` (that is the package that Ubuntu will offer to automatically install when it detects B43 hardware)

Comment: sudo apt-get purge b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'b43-fwcutter' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'firmware-b43-installer' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.